# Change group legend behaviour in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, table-of-contents

In QGIS 2, when you click on a group which contains subgroups, all subgroups are checked/unchecked at the same time.

In QGIS 3, when you click on the same group, only that group is checked. Its subgroups remain unchanged.

I know there's an option in the submenu when you right-click the group, you can check/uncheck all of its children:

[image: QGIS 3 group submenu]

But is there a way this happens when you just click on the group instead of going through the menu? Is there a UI setting somewhere or some basic python code to achieve the same behaviour as in QGIS 2?